# Move still-buffered stdin line down by one when there is output

Tags: python, tty, ansi-escape

I have written a simple chat program in python.
You just have a simple input() prompt (using readline) which should always be on the bottom.

```
partner: hey
you > (stdin)
```

Now, I am trying this without using curses and I have had success by defining these two constants

```py
CURSOR_UP_ONE = '\x1b[1A'
ERASE_LINE = '\x1b[2M'
```

which I use like this whenever a message from 'partner' is received:

```py
print(ERASE_LINE + CURSOR_UP_ONE)
print('partner > ' + msg)
print('you > ')
```

This works fine, however, there is one problem: When I start typing just as a message from 'partner' comes in, it erases the line including what I typed (which I am then no more able to access) and the erased characters are obviously still part of what input() returns.

So, is there a way of moving down the input prompt without curses or a way to buffer the typed in characters to be able to access, display and manipulate them?

Comment: You probably want to avoid the `\n` from `print` in the first place rather than using `cuu1` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved my problem.
I discovered the module `rl`. I use it this way:

```py
import rl.readline as readline

# code

print(ERASE_LINE + CURSOR_UP_ONE)
print('partner > ' + msg)

readline.redisplay(True)
```

This just redisplays the prompt including what I typed (just what I wanted).

Answer (score 0):

If you put the terminal in raw mode (using module `termios`), and handle every keystroke as it's typed, then you will *know* whether or not there is any buffered input before you print the partner's message.

(Also, how are receiving the messages from the partner (socket?) and how are you multiplexing input from the TTY vs the partner?)